# gpg decryption block size limit

Tags: unix, hadoop, encryption, hdfs, gnupg

I'm having an issue with the gpg decryption where I'm decrypting & performing some basic operations on big files. The normal decrypted file is of 60G & after decryption it inflates to 450G.

Decryption, then rowcount (wc -l) is done within HDFS layer only; below is the code snippet

```
rowCount=`hdfs dfs -cat ${hdfsDir}/{fileName} | decrypt | wc -l`
```

The "decrypt" above should be replaced by the gpg --decrypt ... command. I didn't write it here just to avoid it.
For small sized files like 2~3Gigs, the code works fine. But for large file like the size I mentioned above, the decryption throws below error:

```
gpg: block_filter 0x7f2cf62547c0: read error (size=14560,a->size=14560)
gpg: block_filter 0x7f2cf624c990: read error (size=14900,a->size=14900)
gpg: mdc_packet with invalid encoding
gpg: decryption failed: Invalid packet
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
```

Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Comment: There is a misconception, encryption/decryption does not change the data size more than a dozen bytes. Compression can drastically change the file size. So, what exactly is happening, the question is vague on that. Suggest working with small size files and examining the data at each step. Provide a [mcve],

Comment: Ok. I don't think there's any other compression algo I'm running other than gpg encryption/decryption. Perhaps it'd be more clear if I put the encryption/decrytion commands here:

Encryption:
`gpg --recipient myMail@mail.com --encrypt <FILENAME>`

Decryption:
`cat FILENAME.gpg | gpg --batch --passphrase-file passPhraseFile --yes --recipient myMail@mail.com --decrypt`

There's no compression happening here; at all. Hope this is a Minimal one for a start.

Comment: OK, then does gpg also provide compression? You should know that if you are using it.

Comment: I know that compression is there based on output that I see, but no I wasn't aware what kind of compression gpg is doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "block size limit". Data encryption encrypts byte to byte on block size chunks (16-bytes for AES). Up to a block of data may be added to pad the last bytes to a full block, which is removed on decryption.

gpg be default compresses and then encrypts. So it is the compression/decompression that is causing the size to increase of decryption.

Note: I googled: "gpg compression" and the top hit question is: "Does GNU GPG compress by default?" and the first answer is: "Yes" and "the default is to 'ZIP'".